# Complex type parameters for OData functions in Swashbuckle.OData

Tags: c#, .net, odata, swagger, swashbuckle

I have OData function:

```
public class ItemsController : ODataController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SomeFunc([FromODataUri]SomethingDTO something)
    {
        return Ok(1);
    }
}
```

SomethingDTO:

```
public class SomethingDTO
{
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

And ODataConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Configure(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();
        builder.EntitySet<Item>("Items");

        var itemsEntityType = builder.EntitySet<Item>("Items").EntityType;

        var func = itemsEntityType.Collection.Function("SomeFunc");
        func.Parameter<SomethingDTO>("something");
        func.Returns<int>();

        config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
    }
}
```

This works fine, but when I open swagger page, app throws exception:*An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in Swashbuckle.OData.dll but was not handled in user code
ParameterName: TypeKind*

When I remove this string `func.Parameter<SomethingDTO>("something");` from OData config, Swagger page works correctly.But OData function breaks down.

How to define complex parameter for OData function in Swashbuckle.OData?

.NET 4.5.2

Microsoft.AspNet.OData version="6.0.0"

Swashbuckle version="5.6.0"

Swashbuckle.Core version="5.6.0"

Swashbuckle.OData version="3.5.0"

Comment: Same issue with me but I am using Microsoft.Aspnet.OData 7.1.0, Swashbuckle.Core 5.6.0 Swashbuckle.OData 3.5.0